# Uploading a file into a popup window with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have searched the forums and found some information regarding this, but not quite with the problem I'm facing.  I am automating the uploading of files to a website.  Unfortunately, the website uses a counter for the id of the "browse" button.  Using Selenium and Firebug, I was able to find another way to identify the button.  I have exported the script into python to add variables so I can automate.  However, the browse button opens a windows popup to select the file.  The script is started out like this...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type=\"file\"]").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("upfile_1405369589849").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("upfile_1405369589849").send_keys("path\\file")
driver.find_element_by_id("upload_button").click()
```

In this, the upload button is clicked, the popup appears, and it sits there mocking me.  I tried using the xpath in place of the id, but that didn't work.  I tried the following, too...

```
driver.findElement(By.id()).send_keys("path\\file")
```

and tried this...

```
driver.find_element_by_id("upfile_*").send_keys("path\\file")
```

I cant seem to get the window to respond, other than it's mocking glare.  Any help to squelch this would be very appreciated.

Comment: When you send keys, the file element get populated with the path?

Comment: I the popup window the standard browser file upload popup or is it something created by HTML/JavaScript? Sometime there are even flash based upload dialogues. You can only access HTML/JavaScript elements via Selenium.

Comment: @Sebastian The popup window is generated from the OS (windows).  Someone just posted that I will need a secondary app to accomplish this, so I'll start investigating that.

Comment: @Amey That's what it was supposed to do.  I'm told this isn't possible with an OS generated window, so I'll be going a different direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can´t be done. One workaround is to get the development team to modify the AUT for you. Add a javascipt function into the page that will allow you to pass the filename to the handler without having to click the browse button.

If you can´t do that, I would suggest that you look into [Sikuli](http://doc.sikuli.org/) that will allow you to interact with the windows prompt using pattern recognition (screenshots) of what you want to interact with.

Comment: Thank you for that. At least I'll stop banging my head against the wall.  I'll look into Sikuli.